# How to refer payload which is a ResultSet Iterator in mule dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

Sql query returns a streamed output as Resultset iterator object from the Database component. 
i want to convert this to xml in dataweave. But don't know how to refer the incoming object,
If it's a map i can access it simply by using .operator like payload.student

Tried using payload.next() but it gives an error. Also tried the following,
%var input1 payload as :iterator but still wont' work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the steps:

- Drag and drop the Transform Message (Dataweave) component after your configured DB Connector. You will see that the input payload for dataweave script is filled with the db result **`List<Map>`**.
- Then you can access the fields, using the **map** function in dw.

**dw script**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    "Results":{
        (payload map {
            "key1":$."db_field1",
            "key2":$."db_field2"
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code (XML) and a screenshot of dataweave or debugger?
My first guess would be to use a standard transfomer to transform that object to a list or map before the dataweave transformer.